# Matplotlib - Only show one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm got a few plots that my code generates. I want to save all of them, but I only want to display one. I can do the save part just fine, but getting only one to display is proving a pain.

Been going round in circles with trying to achieve this. The closest I got was to clear all but one of the figures, but they all were displayed when I tried to show just one. Starting to think it's either something very simple I'm overlooking or else it's not possible.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Edit: Added sample code. Apologies for not doing so originally.

```
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], label="Test", color='g')
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16],  label="Other Test",  color='r')
    plt.grid(True)

    fig1.savefig('Foo1.png')

    fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 5, 1, 9, 2], label="Test 2", color='g')
    plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 10, 50, 0, 10],  label="Other Test 2",  color='r')
    plt.grid(True)

    fig2.savefig('Foo2.png')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: In order to help, some code would help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My apologies, I had originally intended to do so but then decided as it seemed quite a generic issue it wouldn't be needed. Clearly I was wrong and I'll go update the main post.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot just `del` the figures you don't want to display because mpl retains a reference.  And clearing the figure does not stop it from displaying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can close each figure just after you save it using `plt.close()`. Just be sure to not make a close statement after the last figure.

Your code will look like this:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], label="Test", color='g')
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16],  label="Other Test",  color='r')
plt.grid(True)

fig1.savefig('Foo1.png')
# add plt.close() after you've saved the figure
plt.close()

fig2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 5, 1, 9, 2], label="Test 2", color='g')
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 10, 50, 0, 10],  label="Other Test 2",  color='r')
plt.grid(True)

fig2.savefig('Foo2.png')

plt.show()
```

Comment: That it's! Gah, knew I was overlooking something really simple. I thought the plt.close() command could only work after showing the plots, didn't realise it worked after saving them.

Thank you!

Comment: Python 2.7 on Windows: this approach generates `can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"`

Comment: Same here on python 3, Linux :\

Comment: Is there a way of achieving this without closing the other figures?